# Can I add python callable in gcs to big query operator airflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I am trying to upload a json file from Google Cloud storage to big query. But this json file needs preprocessing before it is pushed to big query. I am planning to use airflow operator `gcs_to_bq`. In this case, how to process the json data ? Please enlighten me with ideas. I can also use *python_operator* but if there is any clean solution to use the existing operator, then it is good as well.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [gcs_to_bq](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_to_bq.html) operator is basically wrapping the BigQuery functionality to [load a JSON file from storage](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#loading_json_files_from). This means that the JSON data goes directly from GCS to BigQuery without passing through the Composer cluster.

In addition, the load operation does not have options to specify a python_callable or to preprocess the data in another way. With this in mind, using a `python_operator` for the pre-processing seems to be a good option.

If the amount of data is significant and it starts causing memory issues on the cluster, you can consider using alternatives such as [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs) to preprocess the data before inserting it into BigQuery. [Here's](https://medium.com/datamindedbe/how-to-build-a-cleaning-pipeline-with-bigquery-and-dataflow-on-gcp-3d2f288d4e1b) an example.

Comment: Thank you :) . I will make use of python_operator itself